# SPARQLWrapper - simple queries with no response

Tags: python, sparql, ontology, rdfs, sparqlwrapper

I'm looking for some help getting this very simple query started, so I can build upon it. At the moment I'm not retrieving any results, but this query works in Protege.

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, XML

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")

sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX pz: <http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

    SELECT ?pizza
    WHERE {
        ?pizza rdfs:subClassOf pz:NamedPizza .
    }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is being sent to DBpedia database.

The query contains pz:NamedPizza.

DBpedia does not have `<http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>` information so the query pattern does not match using the data of DBpedia.

When you query Protege it does have your local pizza data so the query has results.